# Choosing a damping factor in a RLC Low-pass filter

Tags: filter

I have some basic understanding of what the damping factor from control theory. However, I don't know how I should choose it.

We have 24VDC which goes through a input power filter (RLC low-pass filter) and to a buck converter which converts to 5VDC.

I suppose to tune it as close to 1 without causing too much effect in the resistor is one way to go.

Comment: DId you know this website has a schematic function? You can add it to your post by clicking "edit".

Comment: Where are you putting the resistor? In series with the cap or in series with the inductor? If you put it in series with the inductor, it will lead to power loss in the input. If you put it in series with the capacitor, it will not add power loss to the DC current path. And when you think about it, you may be able to achieve the same effect by just using an electrolytic capacitor with no series R (since the electrolytic capacitor has some series resistance built-in).